# Как кешировать скомпилированные шаблоны в AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spa

Изначально `angular` кеширует только сами шаблоны что бы не грузить их снова с сервера, без компиляции с помощью `$cacheFactory`.
В проекте у меня есть несколько мест где используется одна и та же директива.
Я не хочу что бы шаблон снова компилировался при переходе на другую страницу (допустим это SPA, я перешел на /restaurants с /deliveries, а потом снова на /deliveries), а брался с кеша и вставлялся в страницу.
Можно ли как-то это сделать для шаблонов? Типа указал при создании директивы или роута cache: true

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _другой страницей_? почему ты думаешь что сейчас снова компилируется? как ты себе представляешь кэш директивы?

Comment: Извиняюсь, кеш шаблона

Comment: все равно не совсем понятно что ты хочешь. Если у тебя убирался элемент из DOM, то без компиляции и связывания заново не обойтись. Если не убирался - то и сейчас компиляция повторно не вызывается. Попробуй добавить пример кода/разметки чтобы было понятно что ты имеешь ввиду

Comment: Если у тебя убирался элемент из DOM, то без компиляции и связывания заново не обойтись. Я вот про это и имею виду. При первой компиляции шаблона он вносится в кеш, элемент из DOM убирается, а потом вместо того что бы снова компилировать шаблон и связывать, можно просто взять этот элемент с кеша и вставить в DOM. Так можно сделать ?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что сейчас происходит не так? как ты проверял?

Comment: исследовал исходный код angular, там я не нашел кеширования скомпилированных шаблонов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51048/discussion-between-grundy-and-jashka).